# Pipe-safe transparent buffering in c++ ostreams

Tags: c++, buffer, iostream

I have a pair of programs where I'm writing many short lines of data like `A=123 B=456 ...data...\n` to cout and other file output streams, around 50 chars length each. Pipes are involved so I need atomic writes, I started by simply flushing every line write, but by now the flushing has become the main bottleneck in both programs.

I would like all my output streams (including cout) to batch content they receive through `<<` up to `PIPE_BUF` and flush without splicing individual lines (if the new content would overflow the buffer, the new content does not get spliced). I tried doing something like `std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(new char[PIPE_BUF], PIPE_BUF - 200)` hoping this would be the implemented behaviour if the buffer was small, but it seems the call doesn't do anything.

Effectively I want the effect of the following code sample on both `cout` and any other ostreams I open; I can adjust the streams once but it has to work transparently on writes.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h> // PIPE_BUF
#include <random>
// #include <format>
// using std::format;
#include <fmt/format.h>
using fmt::format;

unsigned SAFE_BUF = PIPE_BUF - 200;
bool flushing = false;

int main() {
    unsigned pending = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < 300'000; l++) {
        int A = rand() % 1000, B = rand() % 1000, L = rand() % 40, c = rand() % 26;
        std::string text = format("A={} B={} {}\n", A, B, std::string(L, 'a' + c));
        if (pending + text.size() >= SAFE_BUF) std::cout.flush(), pending = 0;
        std::cout << text, pending += text.size();
        if (flushing) std::cout.flush(), pending = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rm -f test.log
for _ in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do ./writer >>test.log & done && wait
grep -q --invert-match "^A" test.log && echo MANGLED || echo OK
```

Comment: "flushing every line write", well that's the very definition of "atomic write". If this turns out to be a "bottleneck" then the next step is to go back to the drawing board, and come up with a different approach. No amount of fiddling with streambuf is going to change that.

Comment: I made very clear what I want, and the code I have shown here literally fixes my problem, I just want it to work transparently. If the answer is "it can't work transparently" that's an alright resolution. Go annoy someone else please @SamVarshavchik

Comment: My most humble apologies, It's just that I have no idea what "work transparently" means. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I think you should take a look on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/syncstream and possibly spdlog to check if one of them fit your needs.

If not, you may have to write an own stream or manually buffer those messages. Flush them in an interval of e.g. 1s.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just want to hide the pending logic somewhere behind cout (and other ostreams I open), I can set it up somehow in the beginning of main, for example. If I have to wrap it in a function then I always have to use that function and that's far from ideal for something like cout.

Comment: @FabianKeßler interesting but it seems it's for addressing atomic writes across threads? here I have writes across processes, I'll read on it further

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to implement my own subclass of `std::streambuf`, and use that with all `ostream`s, with explicit flushes. Or, perhaps, use a reserved character, maybe `|`, that, once written to the streambuf, triggers the flush (excluding the `|`). A lot depends on the details.

Comment: @elbrunovsky sorry I overlooked that. What about file locking, lock a file, write for a second, release the file. Or you could create an observer process, only for those messages. That process can write them out serially. The other processes connect via IPC.